# Assigning values to arrays in a structure in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
struct student {
int marks[3];
int numberofsubjects[3];
};
```

I create :
struct student student;

in my .c file,

If I try to assign using

```
student.marks = {99,99,99};
```

I do see the **error: expected expression before ‘{’ token**

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: That struct definition isn't even compiling for me on Clang, GCC or MSVC since they all expect a struct to only have at most one flexible array as the last member of the struct

Comment: Sorry I missed out on the array size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign multiple values to array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535410/assign-multiple-values-to-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use an initializer when you define a variable. You can't define a variable, then try to initialize it later using an initializer. You will either have to *assign* values to the elements of the array fields of your structure, or use an initializer at the point of definition.

```
struct student student = { { 99, 99, 99 },
                           { 1, 2, 3 } };
```

Or better yet, use *designated initializers*:

```
struct student student = { .marks = { 99, 99, 99 },
                           .numberofsubjects = { 1, 2, 3 }};
```

Comment: Can I have struct student s; defined in .h file and in my .c file as s =  { .marks = { 99, 99, 99 },
                           .numberofsubjects = { 1, 2, 3 }};

Comment: @ShivaniSarin -- no. You could declare the _type_ `struct student {}` in the `.h.` file, but you can only use the initializer when you define `s` with `struct student s = { .marks = { 99, 99, 99 }, /* ... */ };`. That definition could be (and should be) in a `.c` file.

Comment: I am having struct student defined in my .h file and in my .c file i have struct student s ; s = { .marks = { 99, 99, 99 },...} -> will this work?It is throiwng an errror for me

Comment: @ShivaniSarin -- again, that will not work. You can _only_ use initializer syntax at the point of definition. You can not separate `struct student s;` from `s = /*...*/;`. The only way this works is with `struct student s = { /*...*/};` on the same line. The `struct student s` is the _definition_ of the variable `s`. If you do this: `struct student s;` then `s = /*...*/;`, you attempt initialization after definition (really you attempt an illegal assignment. With `struct student s = { '*...*/};` you define and initialize on the same line.

Comment: I got your point. :) But what if I am setting this in one function and want to use it in another. in this case how do I set it as a global variable?

Comment: It would be best by far to not use global variables. But, if you must, you can define `struct student s = { .marks = { 99, 99, 99 }, /*...*/ };` outside of `main()`. then the variable `s` will be visible to any functions in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that you are missing is that you cannot assign complete arrays; this is only allowed in the course of the definition of a variable (this is then called initialization), but its not allowed any more once the variable has been defined.

See the following initialization (which is allowed):

```
struct student {
    int marks[3];
    int numberofsubjects[3];
};

int main() {
    struct student s = { {1,2,3},{3,4,5}};  // in the course of variable definition; OK, this is "initialization"

    // s.marks = { 2,3,4 }; // illegal assignment of array
    return 0;
}
```