# exchange index in 2D array using pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d, swap

I have a problem to exchange the values of an index in a 2D array by using a pointer. My code for example has an two dimensional array with the initialization `{{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5}}` and I want to exchange the values of two indexes in the 2D array. I created a function named `swap` like this:

```
void swap(double points[20][2],int i, int j){
    double *a,*b;
    a= *(*(points +i)+ 0;
    *(*(points +i)+ 0 = points[j][0];
    *(*(points +j)+ 0 = a;
    b= *(*(points +i)+ 1;
    *(*(points +i)+ 1 = points[j][1];
    *(*(points +j)+ 1 = a;
}
```

`i`,`j` here mean I want to change index `i` to `j` and vice-versa so for example when I used `swap(points,0,1)` the 2D array points will change like this: `{{2,3},{1,2},{3,4},{4,5}}`
Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are

```
void swap( double points[][2], size_t i, size_t j )
{
    double ( *a )[2] = points + i;
    double ( *b )[2] = points + j;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        double tmp = ( *a )[i];
        ( *a )[i] = ( *b )[i];
        ( *b )[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Or entirely without the subscript operator

```
void swap( double points[][2], size_t i, size_t j )
{
    double ( *a )[2] = points + i;
    double ( *b )[2] = points + j;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        double tmp = *( *a + i );
        *( *a  + i ) = *( *b  + i );
        *( *b + i ) = tmp;
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   2

void swap( double points[][N], size_t i, size_t j )
{
    double ( *a )[N] = points + i;
    double ( *b )[N] = points + j;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        double tmp = *( *a + i );
        *( *a  + i ) = *( *b  + i );
        *( *b + i ) = tmp;
    }
} 

int main(void) 
{
    double points[][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 4 }, { 4, 5 }
    };

    const size_t M = sizeof( points ) / sizeof( *points );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        printf( "{ %.1f, %.1f } ", points[i][0], points[i][1] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    swap( points, 0, 1 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        printf( "{ %.1f, %.1f } ", points[i][0], points[i][1] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
{ 1.0, 2.0 } { 2.0, 3.0 } { 3.0, 4.0 } { 4.0, 5.0 } 
{ 2.0, 3.0 } { 1.0, 2.0 } { 3.0, 4.0 } { 4.0, 5.0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can treat 2D array as a pointer to 1D arrays, and do a swap using a temporary array, like this:

```
void swap(double points[20][2],int i, int j) {
    double tmp[2];
    memcpy(tmp, points+i, sizeof(*points));
    memcpy(points+i, points+j, sizeof(*points));
    memcpy(points+j, tmp, sizeof(*points));
}
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/VDfWck)

The implementation is the classic swap, i.e.

```
tmp = points[i];
points[i] = points[j];
points[j] = tmp;
```

but since arrays in C cannot be assigned as a unit, `memcpy` is used instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. what is memcpy? memory copy right?

Comment: @Schrodinger [Correct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy). More info [on array assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3535434/335858).